# Spring boot application can't see beans when run as a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

My spring boot web app works when run it in eclipse but when I try to run as an executable jar it fails to register any of the beans.

The configuration is all annotated - there are no xml config files.

I used `mvn clean compile` and `mvn package` commands to generate the jar.

Has anyone had a similar problem or have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Any corresponding error messages?

Answer (score 3):

Executable jars can not include nested jars, so it is necessary to workaround that limitation. A common approach is to shade the jars (i.e. unpacking all jars, and then packing in to single jar).

Spring-boot takes a different approach that relies on a custom maven repackaging plugin and handling by the Spring Boot Loader module. It generally just works, but per the documentation:

> The spring-boot-starter-parent POM includes  configuration
>   to bind the repackage goal. If you are not using the parent POM you
>   will need to declare this configuration yourself. See the plugin
>   documentation for details.

More information:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar

My guess is that you are are you either not using the spring-boot maven plugin, or are not using the spring-boot parent POM. If that's not the issue, then you will need to post more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, turns out I made a silly error with the project structure. Got it working now

Answer (score 1):

I have now resolved the problem and the app is working as a standalone jar.

Turns out the project folder structure was wrong - such that most of the app was unreachable!

Comment: Please include more details as to what was actually the cause of the problem and how you solved it, as the number of views on your question suggests many people might have a similar issue.